# Why is model instance created twice in RoR model controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

When creating a new model in rails,
in the controller the code goes

```
def new
    @model_name = Model_name.new
end

def create
    @model_name = Model_name.new(model_name_params)
    if @model_name.save
    etc.
    etc.
end
```

Why is it that the `@model_name` instance variable is set twice during the procedure? Isn't the `@model_name` variable in the 'new' action overwritten by the `@model_name` variable in the 'create' action?

I know that `new` action renders a form which does POST to /model_name, which calls `model_name#create`... but I just don't get why it's called in the new action.

Comment: A small example:- say you use same partial (say form.html.erb) for rendering of **new** and **edit** methods. In **edit** you may be using the instance variable (say for calling some model methods, etc), but for **new** the instance variable can't be **nil**, and here, `ModelName.new` will give a empty object, that may solve your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it that the `@model_name` instance variable is set twice during the procedure?

It's not set twice. The procedure requires loading `new` and `create` in two separate calls. These calls will invoke two *instances* of the `Controller` class.

True enough, if you used a *single* instance of the controller, those two variables would be defined at the same time (if you called the two instance methods). However, as each new `request` invokes a single instance of the `Controller`, this does not happen:

[image]

The flow for a Rails controller is:

```
Request > Rack > Routes > Controller.new(request).action > Response
```

Therefore, if the request is routed to `EventsController.new(request).new`, the only data you'll have is `@model_name = ModelName.new`; same for `create`.

To better understand it, you need to become familiar with [Object Orientated Programming (`OOP`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming):

---

## OOP

The reason you have two variables is because you're calling an *instance* of the `Controller`. As with all [object orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), the `@instance` variable provides access to the data across the entire *instance* of a `class`.

If you want your `@instance_variable` available in your view (an extension of the class), it needs to be scoped to the *instance*, not the method.

If you had the following code...

```
def new
  model_name = Model_name.new
end
```

... `model_name` would only be available directly within the `new` method, not the view etc.

Comment: Thanks for the really thorough explanation! That answered all my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because on `new` action you are just initializing the object with empty values so you can create a form, like `form_for @user do |f|` etc.., you'll fill up this form, click submit, params from form will be passed to create action..

On `create` action you are initializing again the object (you are not in new action anymore and previous object is lost, so you create it again), but this time you assign values that comes from params to this object. And right after this you try if this object can be saved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, I still do not understand why the user instance variable is necessary. For the form, is the user instance variable necessary for rails to save it to the params hash? Is it not possible to make a form to send values without the user instance variable?

Comment: It is, but using an instance variable allows you to read existing data, and validation errors, if it fails to save for example.  it also allows you to use the same form for editing and creating a record.

Comment: I'm not quite clear with how that works. What do you mean by read existing data? Also, for the validation error, doesn't the overwriting of the instance variable occur before the @user.save? Sorry for the loads of questions, but I'm having a hard time understanding the usage, even after reading the rails guide :(

Comment: Your `@user` could have default values, that could be pre-populated on the form. Existing data, also sent by the user a first time after a validation error: the norm is to render again the new form with the invalid `@user` so the user doesn't have to fill the entire form again and the form display the errors.

Comment: I forgot to address your overwriting concern, and no. Each request leaves on it's own, so by the time a user hits `create` you are dealing with a new instance of your ModelController, bare new, without a @model_name instance variable set.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It certainly helped me understand